# Wordpress website /Checkout Stripe -Bancontact

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments, checkout

I have activated the Bancontact methode for my Stripe account from Stripe dashboard.
I want to create checkout session from my wordpress website using a plugin connected to my stripe account API Keys.
My customers want to pay with Bancontact. But the problem I have is that the Bancontact option button is not shown on the checkout form. I tried a lot of to resolve that issue but I could not. I contacted with Stripe's support team for help and they recommended me to advice wordpress? and that I must configure a parameter name 'payment_method_data' with 'bancontact'?

Can some one help me resolving this please?

Comment: Did you make bancontact accepted within your stripe account?

Comment: Yes I did. Bancontact is active with my stripe account

Comment: Ok, then did you activate bancontact in the woocommerce payment settings?

Comment: We are not using woocommerce in our website. We do not sell products. We organise events like masterclasses. We need only that our customers book and pay with stripe bancontact. The plugin we are using is WpPayForm wich has the stripe payment option. However bancontact not displayed on checkout form.

Comment: In that case, did you reach out to WpPayForm? They are most likely the ones that cause this problem...